# calling startActivityForResult isn't passing intents back properly

Tags: java, android

In my code, I have a class for a recipe and then another class for each step. The recipe class holds an arraylist of the steps in that recipe.

I have 3 processes being called one after the other:

- MainActivity calls AddEditRecipe using startActivityResult
- within AddEditRecipe I have another startActivityResult which calls AddStep
- within AddStep I am adding a new instance of step to the list in the recipe.

It successfully adds the object to the list before finish() is called, but when I check the size of the list when I have gone to the 2nd activity it has reverted back to 0, even though I've managed to create buttons with the data I collected from the AddStep functions.

Basically I don't know what to do make it so it everything correctly persists.
Also a heads up, I am still fairly new too java so there's probably lots of other things wrong, any random advice is greatly appreciated.

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button newRecipe;
Button editRecipe;
Button deleteRecipe;
LinearLayout recipeLayout;

List<NewRecipe> listOfRecipes;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listOfRecipes = new ArrayList<>();
    recipeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.RecipeListLayout);

    newRecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewRecipeButton);
    newRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddRecipePopUp.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i,998);

        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode==999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        NewRecipe rec = (NewRecipe)data.getParcelableExtra("curr_recipe");
        Log.d("Number of Steps",Integer.toString(rec.listOfSteps.size()));
        UpdateScreen(rec);
    }

    if(requestCode== 998 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        NewRecipe recipe =(NewRecipe)data.getParcelableExtra("curr_recipe");
        listOfRecipes.add(recipe);

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddEditRecipe.class);
        i.putExtra("curr_recipe", recipe);
        startActivityForResult(i,999);
    }
}

void UpdateScreen(final NewRecipe recipe){



       Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(recipe.name);
        button.setHeight(120);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                NewRecipe recipe1 = recipe;
                Button thisBut = (Button)view;
                String butName = thisBut.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
                for(int j = 0;j<listOfRecipes.size();j++){
                    String curr = listOfRecipes.get(j).name.toString().toLowerCase();
                    Log.d("Button ",thisBut.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("Current List ",listOfRecipes.get(j).name.toString().toLowerCase());
                    Log.d("Check bool statement", Boolean.toString(butName ==curr));


                }
                //recipe1 = listOfRecipes.get(0);

                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditRecipe.class);
                i.putExtra("curr_recipe",recipe1);
                startActivityForResult(i,997);

            }
        });
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        recipeLayout.addView(button,lp);

}
}
```

AddEditRecipe

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;


public class AddEditRecipe extends Activity {
Button home;
Button add;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_edit_recipe);



    Intent i = getIntent();
    final NewRecipe this_recipe =  i.getParcelableExtra("curr_recipe");
    Log.d("Number of Steps",Integer.toString(this_recipe.listOfSteps.size()));
    LinearLayout recipeLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.RecipeListLayout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    for(int j = 0; j<this_recipe.listOfSteps.size();j++){
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(this_recipe.listOfSteps.get(j).processName);
        button.setHeight(120);


        recipeLayout.addView(button,lp);
    }

    home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HomeButton);
    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent i = new Intent(AddEditRecipe.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("curr_recipe", this_recipe);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
            Log.d("Number of Steps",Integer.toString(this_recipe.listOfSteps.size()));
            finish();


        }
    });

    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddStepButton);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(AddEditRecipe.this, AddStep.class);
            i.putExtra("curr_recipe", this_recipe);
            startActivityForResult(i,999);
        }
    });

}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(requestCode==999 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        NewRecipe curr_rec = (NewRecipe)data.getParcelableExtra("curr_recipe");

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText(curr_rec.listOfSteps.get(curr_rec.listOfSteps.size()-1).processName + " " + curr_rec.listOfSteps.get(curr_rec.listOfSteps.size()-1).seconds );
        button.setHeight(120);
        LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.RecipeListLayout) ;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lay.addView(button,lp);
    }
}

}
```

AddStep

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class AddStep extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_step);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    final NewRecipe this_recipe = (NewRecipe) i.getParcelableExtra("curr_recipe");

    Button finish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddStepButton);
    finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
            EditText hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HoursEditText);
            EditText minutes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MinutesEditText);
            EditText seconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SecondsEditText);

            this_recipe.AddStep((ConvertToSeconds(Integer.parseInt(hours.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(minutes.getText().toString()),Integer.parseInt(seconds.getText().toString()))),name.getText().toString());

            Intent j = new Intent(AddStep.this, AddEditRecipe.class);
            j.putExtra("curr_recipe", this_recipe);
            Log.d("Number of Steps",Integer.toString(this_recipe.listOfSteps.size()));
            setResult(RESULT_OK,j);
            finish();

        }
    });
}

int ConvertToSeconds(int h, int m, int s){

    int ans = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<h;i++){
        ans+=3600;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<m;i++){
        ans+=60;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<s;i++){
        ans++;
    }


    return ans;
}
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: use fields instead of local variables. One thing which seems to go wrong is that your recipe list in the middle `Activity` is only a local variable (in `onCreate()` ). You use it successfully to populate the `LinearLayout` but because it is a local variable and not a field (a variable which is visible everywhere in its class), you can't pass the result to this list in `onActivityResult()`. Instead you  use another local variable to update the `LinearLayout`. But this way the result (the data) will be lost once the method is finished athough the `View`s look fine.

Comment: Ahhhhh, that makes sense
all sorted now, thankyou :)

Comment: okay so new issue,
in the listener event in the UpdateScreen() I need to bring through an instance of the same instance of recipe every time I use it
it works for the first time I click on it but if I then add a step to it after I click on it and then go back it doesn't keep the new step that got added
So basically how do I make sure the button listener sends the same instance everytime?

Comment: this is a new problem, so you should ask a new question with all the relevant code snippets (because that's how stack overflow works). I'll look into the problem if you do so.